# Как правильно связать две таблицы

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Проект Spring-Boot и Thymeleaf
Три сущности

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "peoples", schema = "public", catalog = "people")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Getter
@Setter
@DynamicUpdate
@DynamicInsert
@SelectBeforeUpdate
public class PeopleEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "children_id")
    private ChildrenEntity сhildrenEntityId;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private BloodgroupEntity bloodgroupEntity;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "childrens", schema = "public", catalog = "blood_group")
...
public class BloodgroupEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private PeopleEntity peopleEntity;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "peoples", schema = "public", catalog = "children")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Getter
@Setter
@DynamicUpdate
@DynamicInsert
@SelectBeforeUpdate
public class ChildrenEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    id_children BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( pk_people )
)
ALTER TABLE public.people ADD CONSTRAINT fk_children FOREIGN KEY (id_children) REFERENCES children(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE public.people ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cblood_group FOREIGN KEY (id_blood_group) REFERENCES blood_group(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE

CREATE TABLE blood_group (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    id_children BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( pk_blood_group )
)
CREATE TABLE children (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( pk_children )
)
```

Контроллеры:

```
private List<OperationTableEntity> peopleEntityList;
private List<ChildrenEntity> childrenEntityList;

@GetMapping(value = "/add-product-type")
public String showPeople(@ModelAttribute("peopleEntityList") PeopleEntity peopleEntity
         Model model) {
    peopleEntityList = peopleEntityService.getAll();
    childrenEntityList = childrenEntityService.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("peopleEntityList", peopleEntityList);
    model.addAttribute("childrenEntityList", childrenEntityList);
    return "add-people";
 }



 @PostMapping(value = "/people/new")
public String createPeople(@ModelAttribute("peopleEntity") PeopleEntity peopleEntity) {
    peopleEntityService.save(peopleEntity);
    return "redirect:/add-product-type";
}
```

файл add-people.html:

```html
....
<form id="f-prt-01" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/people/new}" th:object="${peopleEntity}" name="formPrType">
    <div class="form-group mt-1">
        <label for="inputName">Имя</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Имя" th:field="*{name}" autofocus required>

        <label for="inputGroupSelect02">группа</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">

            <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect02" th:field="*{сhildrenEntityId}">
                <option th:each="bloodgroupTable : ${bloodgroupEntityList}"
                        th:value="${bloodgroupTable.id}"
                        th:text="${bloodgroupTable.name}"/>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

Подскажите правильно я реализовал код для таблиц PeopleEntity и BloodgroupEntity.
Т.е. у одного человека может быть только одна группа крови. Сделал по аналогии в обучающих курсах. Они правда у всех разные.

Answer (score 0):

1. в таблице people не хватает колонки id_blood_group, вы объявили ограничение на колонку которой нет в таблице
2. в PRIMARY KEY нужно указывать стоблец, то есть для всех таблиц это будет id
3. В аннотации @Table атрибут name указывает на имя таблицы, вряд ли вы хотите хранить ChildrenEntity в таблице и именем @Table(name = "peoples", .... Пересмотрите также в других аннотациях @Table

Можете удалить add-people.html и контроллеры из вопроса, они к нему не относятся